# Как Метод fuelneeded высчитывает необходимое количество топлива?

Tags: java

Учусь java по Шилдту - разбираю одну программу. И вот тут метод fuelneeded должен рассчитывать количество gallons для того чтобы проехать 252 мили.
Я просто смотрю - в методе fuelneeded введена переменная miles и количество миль делится на расход топлива. Откуда мы берем количество миль???
Программка работает - количество Галлонов и для Минивэна и для Спорткара высчитываются. Но как это происходит объясните пожалуйста максимально популярно...

```
public class Vehicle {
int passengers;
int fuelcap;
int mpg;

int range() {        //ВОТ ЭТОТ КУСОЧЕК ЕСТЬ В ПРОГРАММКЕ, НО РЕАЛЬНО ОН НЕ НУЖЕН ПОХОЖЕ
    return mpg * fuelcap;
}

double fuelneeded(int miles) {                //МЕТОД fuelneeded
    return (double) miles / mpg;
}
```

}

```
class CompFuel {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
    Vehicle sportcar = new Vehicle();
    double gallons;
    int dist = 252;

    minivan.passengers = 7;
    minivan.fuelcap = 16;
    minivan.mpg = 21;

    sportcar.passengers = 2;
    sportcar.fuelcap = 14;
    sportcar.mpg = 12;

    gallons = minivan.fuelneeded(dist);

    System.out.println("Для преодоления " + dist + " миль мини-фургону требуется "
            + gallons + " галлонов топлива");

    gallons = sportcar.fuelneeded(dist);

System.out.println("Для преодоления " + dist + " миль спортивному автомобилю требуется " +
            gallons + " галлонов топлива");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод fuelneeded(dist) для минивена и передаете целочисленное(int) число dist равное 252:

```
minivan.fuelneeded(dist);
```

Метод получает копию числа в переменную miles:

```
double fuelneeded(int miles)
```

Выполняет miles(252)/mpg(12) и возвращает число с плавающей точкой(double) обратно в main

Вот тут очень подробно объясняют про методы https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/chto-takoe-metody-v-java/

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо)))